# How to play sound directly into software recorder?

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording, digital-audio

Without having it go outside via speaker system and back into the machine via its microphone?  I have a Lenovo ThinkPad (Windows 7) and I can't figure out how to just keep my speakers turned down and have a player from a website transmit the audio signal directly to an application listening for it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), an open source sound editing program, supports recording directly from the sound card.  Simply select "stereo mixer" (or similar) from the source dropdown in the toolbar, and press record.